# How to enable true remote login

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, remote

I don't quite know how these things are called, so a search did not product any help.

I've got two computers, a desktop and a netbook. The netbook is really weak, and there's hardly any fun doing work with it, especially after ubuntu software swallows so much cpu power for nothing. But my desktop is good, but uncomfortably positioned.

So I know you can use any linux system as a server to give logins. I want to be able to login and work on my desktop, from my netbook. No VNC, no SSH, full X-server, I want to be able to choose "Login on Desktop" in my login menu on the netbook and have everything as if I was there.

I hope I could make my point. Is it possible in a local network? And if so, how can I easily set it up?

Comment: Well you won't be happy if you don't have a really fast LAN.

Comment: @con-f-use LAN by definition should be fast enough. (Not to mention that I work on a remote X11 session over the internet on a regular basis using NX.)

Comment: You can run full X-Session over SSH. Setting up unencrypted X sessions over network is much more of a hassle. Just `ssh -X ip.of.your.desk` and run `gnome-session`.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using on the two machines?

Comment: Uh, always the latest. But that doesn't matter any more, I bought a new laptop and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Xnest is what you're looking for:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xnest

Although how you set it up as a session within the login screen is a mystery to me I'm afriad.

Comment: Hmm, that kind of worked, but it ignores the arrow, shift and control keys. and as for the session in the login screen, I read someone really, really smart removed that option entirely from ubuntu's `gdm` login screen.

Comment: "Wikipedia does not have an article with this exact name"